# CS50 PSET2 CAESAR clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf ("Usage: ./caesar k\n");
    return 1;
}
int k = atoi (argv[1]);

printf ("plaintext: ");
string p = get_string ();

printf ("ciphertext: ");

for (int i = 0, n = strlen (p); i < n; i++)
{
    if (isupper (p[i]))
    {
        int alpha = p[i];
        alpha = alpha - 65;
        alpha = (alpha + k) % 26;

        char cipher = alpha + 65 ;

        printf ("%c", cipher);
    }  
    else if (islower (p[i]))
    {
        int alpha = p[i];
        alpha = alpha - 97;
        alpha = (alpha + k) % 26;

        char cipher = alpha + 97 ;

        printf ("%c", cipher);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("%c", p[i]);
    }
}
printf ("\n");
return 0;
}
```

The program works perfectly without 'return 0' at the end but the cs50 pset 
specifically states that the program should exit by returning 0 from main. What 
have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine for me. What is the exact error you're getting?

Testing without wraparound:

```
$./stack_question 5
plaintext: Hello
ciphertext: Mjqqt
```

Testing wraparound:

```
$./stack_question 36
plaintext: Hello
ciphertext: Rovvy
```

Also, can you try running a simple hello world program on the workspace? If not, I'd suggest you create a new workspace (CS50 IDE -> Dashboard -> Create new workspace) Sometimes the c9 workspace messes up on me and I can't even run a simple hello world program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
if (argc != 2)
{
    printf ("Usage: ./caesar k\n");
    return 1;
}
int k = atoi (argv[1]);

printf ("plaintext: ");
string p = get_string ();

printf ("ciphertext: ");

for (int i = 0, n = strlen (p); i < n; i++)
{
    if (isupper (p[i]))
    {
        int alpha = p[i];
        alpha = alpha - 65;
        alpha = (alpha + k) % 26;

        char cipher = alpha + 65 ;

        printf ("%c", cipher);
    }  
    else if (islower (p[i]))
    {
        int alpha = p[i];
        alpha = alpha - 97;
        alpha = (alpha + k) % 26;

        char cipher = alpha + 97 ;

        printf ("%c", cipher);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("%c", p[i]);
    }
}
printf ("\n");
return 0;
}
```